# Foreign Key related form Saving in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

My Models are look like .....

```
Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 60, blank = False)
    r_no = models.CharField(max_length = 60, blank = False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(null = False, blank = False, default = datetime.datetime.now())

StudentPotential(models.Model):
    aka_name = models.CharField(max_length = 60, blank = True)
    -----
    -----
StudentCorrespondence(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey('Student', related_name = "Student_FK")
    student_p = models.ForeignKey('Student', related_name = "Student_FK")
    emailed_date = models.DateTimeField(null = True, blank = True)
    phoned_date = models.DateTimeField(null = True, blank = True)
```

My Form in form.py

```
class StudentPotentialForm (forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = StudentPotential

class StudentCorrespondenceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StudentCorrespondence
        exclude = ('student', 'student_p')
```

Finally My view.py

```
def add_student_company_potential(request, student_id):
    from cdradmin.forms import StudentPotentialForm, StudentCorrespondenceForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
            ### HOW TO SAVE THE two from for the student have its it 'student_id' ####

    else:

            StudentPotentialForm = StudentPotentialForm()
            StudentCorrespondenceForm = StudentCorrespondenceForm()
context = {'StudentCorrespondenceForm':StudentCorrespondenceForm, "StudentPotentialForm":StudentPotentialForm}
return render_to_response('cdradmin/studentform.html', context, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Once the data is post to the view, How can i able to save this data for the student has his/her id is  'student_id'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    spf = StudentPotentialForm(request.POST)
    if spf.is_valid():
        osp = spf.save()
    else :
       #raise error

    student = Student.objects.get(id=student_id)
    scf = StudentCorrespondenceForm(request.POST)
    if scf.is_valid():
        osc = scf.save(commit=False)
        osc.student = student
        osc.student_p = osp
        osc.save()
    else:
        # raise error.
```

Comment: spf.is_valid() always False.this model does not have any special fields .

Comment: Does your html form has appropriate values for the elements? Try `print spf.errors` for form error. For form specific error try: `for k,f in spf.fields.items():  for e in f.error_messages:    print f, e`